# boost spirit: how to match any lexer token in qi?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, boost-spirit-lex

I would like to match a C++ function declaration with default argument values, but ignoring these values.
For example:

```
int myFunction(int a, int b = 5 + 4);
```

Here is (a part of) the lexer:

```
struct Lexer : boost::spirit::lex::lexer<lexer_type>
{
    Lexer()
    {
        identifier = "[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*";
        numLiteral = "([0-9]+)|(0x[0-9a-fA-F]+)";

        this->self.add
            ("int")
            ('+')
            ('=')
            ('(')
            (')')
            (';')
            (',')
            (identifier)
            (numLiteral);
    }
};
```

I would like to write a couple of parser rules like:

```
function = qi::lit("int") >> lexer.identifier >> '(' >> arglist >> ')' >> ';';
arglist = (lexer.numLiteral >> lexer.identifier >> -(lit('=') >> rvalue )) % ',';
rvalue = +(qi::token() - ',' - ')');
```

I've seen [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/what_s_new/spirit_2_4_2.html) that "The parser primitives qi::token and qi::tokenid can now be used without any argument. In this case they will match any token.". Which is what I want (and what I wrote), but unfortunately it does not compile.
qi::token() really needs at leat one argument.
Did I miss something?

Comment: You don't show any SSCCE, so I'm not going waste any time. Have you tried without the parentheses (this is a EDSL  convention, _cf._ `qi::string` vs. `qi::string("value")`)

Comment: Thank you @sehe for the tip: no parentheses. Now it compiles. By the way, what is EDSL?

Comment: Edsl: [Embedded Domain Specific Language](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?EmbeddedDomainSpecificLanguage) (spirit's expressions templates are an example; Phoenix's lazy actors [in semantic actions] are another)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, since this was apparently enough to answer it:

> Which is what I want (and what I wrote), but unfortunately it does not compile. qi::token() really needs at leat one argument. Did I miss something?

Probably you didn't miss enough: did you leave the `()`? Because in the EDSL it's convention to drop the parentheses for the parameter-less version (*cf.* `qi::string` vs. `qi::string("value")`)